# Issues appending strings in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and had written a method to create css/js links, concatenate them and then pass them to my view. It was working before, until I decided to create a clean copy of the project with the latest CI version and it's not working now.

The part of the method that concatenates the data is the following:

```
foreach ($header_css as $item) {
   $str .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. base_url() . $item . '" type="text/css" />';
}
```

There's a similar one for the JS files. When printing the previous piece of code I'm getting an empty string, so I decided to use htmlentities:

```
foreach ($header_css as $item) {
   $str .= htmlentities('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. base_url() . $item . '" type="text/css" />');
}
```

and it works... partially. I mean, if I print at this point the string with the links are there but now when I pass the string to the view the data is being printed on screen instead of being added to the head. So this is my view:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo (isset($title)) ? $title : ''; ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test">
    <meta name="author" content="Test">

    <?php
        # load assets
        echo (isset($assets)) ? $assets : '';
    ?>

    <script>var ajax_home = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajax/";</script>
</head>

<body>
```

The part that echoes the assets is printing the content of the variable on screen instead of parsing the assets as `<script>...</script>` or `<link rel="stylesheet" ... />`

Any indication on why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. Can you post a little bit more code? So where are your foreach placed in, where and how is the variable `$assets` defined? And what do you exactly expect as the HTML output and what is your current output? It would help us to help you ;)

Comment: @be-ndee I'm sorry. Not quite sure what I'm missing in my explanation. What I need is the content of $assets not to be printed on screen but to actually load the assets. Asses is a string like: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/storedashboard/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/storedashboard/assets/DataTables/datatables.min.css" type="text/css" />'. Again, this is what is being printed on screen instead of actually creating the html sources for the assets

Comment: Well your foreach loop is generating $str and your are passing $assets into your view... What and how does that happen? (Note: You should initialise $str before the loop else PHP will throw a warning...

Answer (score 3):

> ***The part of the method that concatenates the data is the following:***

```
foreach ($header_css as $item) {
   $str .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. base_url() . $item . '" type="text/css" />';
}
```

> ***There's a similar one for the JS files. When printing the previous piece of code I'm getting an empty string, so I decided to use
>   htmlentities:*** *Below Code is NOT FOR JavaScript, it's for Style sheet*

```
foreach ($header_css as $item) {
   $str .= htmlentities('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. base_url() . $item . '" type="text/css" />');
}
```

***it should be like,***

```
foreach ($header_js as $item) {
  $str .= "<script type='text/javascript' src='". base_url() . $item . "'/>";
}
```

***& Your Views has (Ahem!):***

```
<?php
  # load assets
  echo (isset($assets)) ? $assets : '';
?>
```

*So, My Question is:*

1. *Where is **$str variable** and why you are not using inside view instead of **$assets** it should be `echo (isset($str)) ? $str : '';`*
2. *I am assuming that you are using your function inside your controller as method & storing all js & css file build in that
   variable. So.. `are you returning that $str variable.. ?`*

*Well, Here is some example for you, Hope you can solve your problem :)*

```
/**
 * Build Css or Script link
 * @param  array  $assets [description]
 * @param  string $type   [description]
 * @return [type]         [description]
 */
function build_assets($assets = array(), $type = 'css')
{
    $str = '';
    if (!empty($assets) && is_array($assets) && $type == 'css') {
        foreach ($assets as $key => $file) {
            $str .= "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" . base_url($file) . ".css' />";
        }
    } elseif (!empty($assets) && is_array($assets) && $type == 'javascript') {
        foreach ($assets as $key => $file) {
            $str .= "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . base_url($file) . ".js'></script>";
        }
    }
    return $str;
}
/**
 * Testing the method
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
function index()
{
    $data = [];
    // get all style sheets
    $style = $this->build_assets(['style', 'page', 'form']);
    // get all js files
    $script = $this->build_assets(['style', 'page', 'form'], 'javascript');
    // assign in 'assets' variable
    $data['assets'] = $style . $script;
    // send to template/view
    $this->load->view('ViewTemplate', $data);
}
```

***& Views Code:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodeIgniter</title>
    <!-- CSS and JavaScript -->
    <?php echo isset($assets) ? $assets : '' ?>
    <!-- End Here -->
</head>
<body>
   <di class="welcome">Say Hello to CodeIgniter!!!</di> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have. My 'build_assets' method is in a helper and I invoke it from the Controller and then pass it to the view. The return from build_assets is returning ' '. If I use htmlentities then it is returning the correct string, but when echoing it in the View it is printing the content into the screen

Comment: The issue is definitely related with the characters < and />. I just removed them from the string and the results are being printed. Do I need to turn on/off any CI settings to allow these characters?

Comment: It is working now (for some reason that I still do not understand). Still, the string is not being printed on screen but the sources are being loaded. Thanks for your help

Comment: @johansebasb Glad I could help you, if you not getting the data or empty value then you can just check by print_r() in your controller or helper function, to know where your code is breaking. I don't think you need htmlentities because you not sending any html character in file name, so just build_assets and print what coming from helper function... & one thing you can see your string by view source. it will not show in page because you are echoing the assets in html head section not in body section..